# Micro average for AUC/ROC

Tags: scikit-learn, roc

The yellowbrick documentation has an example of AUC/ROC [here](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/classifier/rocauc.html#quick-method). It seems odd to me the micro average would have an AUC much bigger than the individual classes or macro average. Is there some reason the micro average AUR is much bigger than macro average or individual class values?

Comment: See [Can Micro-Average Roc Auc Score be larger than Class Roc Auc Scores](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/89180/55122) on DS.SE.

Comment: Thanks, it's explained there. Macro and micro averages don't make much sense for AUC/ROC is the main conclusion.